# video capture from firewire c++ windows

Tags: c++, windows, video-capture, firewire

I'm using eclipse and c++ on windows and I have to capture a video from a firewire camera but I have no ideas of which libraries should I use.

I prefer to not install anything, but using some libraries if it's possible.

if you can also post a code example of how to capture the video it would be very helpfull.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video capture API in Windows is `DirectShow` or `Media Foundation`. With DirectShow you can capture video in a way similar to other video sources (frame grabbers, web cameras etc). See [Capture firewire video: does this require DirectShow?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/1fed59c1-b6f6-41be-bda9-5d2fb32f296e).

Comment: These are core Windows APIs, whatever video capture can be taking place - it is either these APIs or proprietary vendor specific SDKs. I don't know how eclipse works, but most likely it is via one of the mentioned APIs. OpenCV suggested in another answers works via DirectShow.